# getting reference to copied worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any reliable way to get reference to copied Excel worksheet?

```
set copiedWorksheet = someSheet.copy(Before:=anotherWorkbook.worksheets(1))
```

...doesn't work.

this:

```
someSheet.copy Before:=anotherWorkbook.worksheets(1)
set copiedWorksheet = anotherWorkbook.worksheets(1)
```

...is not working properly if original worksheets(1) is hidden

this:

```
someSheet.copy Before:=anotherWorkbook.worksheets(1)
set copiedWorksheet = anotherWorkbook.worksheets(someSheet.name)
```

...is not working properly if anotherWorkbook has worksheet with the same name

Comment: set copiedWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Comment: @Zer0Kelvin Are you sure, that Excel always sets copied sheet as active? Even if application.ScreenUpdating=False or application.visible=False? I'm looking for fully reliable solution

Comment: If you don't trust you can try.